# Prove that int$(A) = \overline{[X-A]}$ where $[X - A]$ is the closure and the bar represents the complement.

Tags: general-topology

Prove that int$(A) = \overline{[X-A]}$ where $[X - A]$ is the closure and the bar represents the complement.

I have seen this proof before but I do like showing things like this via set theory. In other words, if $x \in$ int$(A)$ then ..... and produce the general argument that the left hand side is a subset of the right hand side, and the right hand side is a subset of the left hand side which would imply they are equal. Was curious how it went and would be very appreciative if someone showed me!

Comment: Wow, usually I seen the notation $\overline{A}$ for the closure of $A$.  And $A^{c}$ for the complement of $A$.

Comment: I highly suggest not ever using this notation. Write $X\setminus A$ (X\setminus A) for the complement. $\overline{A}$ (\overline{A}) is almost universally used for closure.

Comment: Check out Introductory Real Analysis by Kolmogorov. Thats what he does.

Comment: Question about sets? Sure, that's what [set-theory] is for! `:|`

Comment: @NickFreeman Even if Kolmogorov does it, it's still a terrible notation. Using $\overline{\hphantom{M}\vphantom{X}}$ to denote the complement is evil (not just bad, evil) when doing topology. It's like using $\frac{d}{dx}$ to denote negation.

Answer (score 3):

**For the $\subseteq$ direction:**

> Let $x \in \text{int}(A)$.  We want to show $x \in \overline{[X - A]}$, that is, we want to show that $x \not \in [X - A]$, where $[X - A]$ is the closure of $X - A$.
>
> Suppose by contradiction that $x$ is in the closure of $X - A$.  Then for every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, $U \cap (X - A) \neq \emptyset$.  But we know since $x \in \text{int}(A)$ that $\exists$ an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $x \in V \subseteq A$.  But we just said earlier that every open neighborhood of $x$ must intersect $X - A$ if $x$ is in the closure of $X - A$.  So it must be the case that $V \cap (X - A) \neq \emptyset$.  Hm...$V \subseteq A$ and $V \cap (X - A) \neq \emptyset$ are contradictory statements.  So we can't have $x$ in the closure of $X - A$, which means $x$ is in the complement of the closure of $X - A$, i.e., $x \in \overline{[X - A]}$.

**Now for the other direction ($\supseteq$):**

> Suppose $x \in \overline{[X - A]}$.  Then $x \not \in [X - A]$, where $[X - A]$ is the closure of $X - A$.  Then since $x$ is **not** in the closure, there must be some open neighborhood $V$ such that $x \in V$ and $V \cap (X - A) = \emptyset$.  But this means $V \subseteq A$.  And so we found an open neighborhood of $x$ that is entirely contained in $A$, which is precisely what we need to conclude $x \in \text{int}(A)$.

Thus, we have $\text{int}(A) \subseteq \overline{[X - A]}$ and $\overline{[X - A]} \subseteq \text{int}(A)$, which means $\text{int}(A) = \overline{[X - A]}$, as desired.

Comment: Let $A={\{0,1}\}$ and $X=[0,1]$. Then how $\text{int}(A) = \overline{[X - A]}$?

Comment: @Edi First of all, you have to understand OP's very unusual notation.  $[X-A]$ represents the closure of $X - A$, and $\bar{[X-A]}$ represents the complement of $[X-A]$.  Ok, so let $A = \{0,1\}$.  int$(A) = \emptyset$, right?  Now, $X - A = (0,1)$.  Since $[X-A]$ is the closure of $X-A$, then $[X-A] =$ the closed interval $[0,1]$.  Now, $\bar{[X-A]}$ is the "complement in $X$" of $[X-A]$.  Since $[X-A] = [0,1] = X$, then the complement of $[X-A]$ in $X$ is $X - [X-A] = [0,1] - [0,1] = \emptyset$, showing that int$(A) = \bar{[X-A]}$.  OP's notation is very weird.

Comment: @Edi OP's notation is nonstandard and I don't recommend you ever use it.  They say $\bar{A}$ represents the complement of $A$, while $\bar{A}$ usually represents the closure of $A$.  Usually, $A^{c}$ represents the complement of $A$.  They say $[A]$ represents the closure of $A$, but I've never seen this before.

Comment: thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

$x \notin \operatorname{Int}(A)$

iff for all open $U$ with $x \in U$, $U \nsubseteq A$

iff for all open $U$ with $x \in U$, we have that $U \cap (X \setminus A) \neq \emptyset$

iff $x \in \overline{X\setminus A}$

So taking complements: $x \in \operatorname{Int}(A)$ iff $x \in X\setminus \overline{X \setminus A}$